# Principal Divisors on a projective non-singular irreducible curve if and only if degree is 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a a projective non-singular irreducible curve under a ground field $k$. Let $D$ be a divisor on $C$ with degree 0. Does this necessarily imply that $D$ is principal? That is, $D=\text{div}f$ for some $f\in k(X)$? Also, since $C$ is birational to a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$, can we assume WLOG that $C$ is such a curve? How does "irreducible nonsingular" help in this case?

I know that there are finitely many points $P_1, ..., P_r\in C$ that gives a nonzero contribution to $D$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "a curve in $\mathbb{P}^1$"? Since $\mathbb{P}^1$ is 1-dimensional, the only projective curve contained in $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathbb{P}^1$ itself. Did you mean $\mathbb{P}^2$ or something?

Comment: Yeah I think so, I will correct it.

Comment: Say $k$ is algebraically closed. Once you know that for all $f\in k(X),\deg(div(f))=0$ then it suffices that one $f\in k(X)$  has $div(f)=P-Q,P\ne Q$ to get that $k(X)=k(f)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of divisors modulo principal divisors is known as the [Picard group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group); the subgroup of degree zero divisors modulo principal divisors is denoted $\newcommand{\Pic}{\operatorname{Pic}}\Pic^0(C)$. When $C$ is a smooth projective curve over a field, $\Pic^0(C)$ is isomorphic to the [Jacobian variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_variety) of $C$, which is an abelian variety of dimension equal to the genus $g$ of $C$, and is birational to $C^{(g)}$, the $g$-th symmetric power of $C$.

So for a curve of genus at least $1$, it's *very* far from true that degree zero divisors are always principal. For example, if $P, Q \in C$ such that $[P] - [Q]$ is principal, then $P = Q$.

As for your question about curves being birational to curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$, note that most curves not of genus $0$, $1$, or $3$ are only birational to a *singular* plane curve, not a *smooth* plane curve.